# Adyen Payment - how to prevent a PayPal popup when the user taps the PayPal button

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment-gateway

I want to do some validation on submit but the problem is a new PayPal window popped up. I don't want the popup unless I do the validation.

```
const paypalComponent = checkout.create("paypal", {
    onSubmit: (state, component) => {
        if(isValidationOk){
            // do your action...
        }else {
            // close the PayPal popup
        }
    }
}).mount("#paypal-container");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the setStatus method with your validation message.

```
const paypalComponent = checkout.create("paypal", {
    onSubmit: (state, component) => {
        if(isValidationOk){
            // do your action...
        }else {
            component.setStatus('error', { message: 'Your validation message.' });

            setTimeout(function () {
                component.setStatus('ready');
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
}).mount("#paypal-container");
```